# How link son with his father by sql statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image: Image for SQL Table data]

I have table in SQL server I want show the data like:

1. Smith
2. Johnson Smith
3. Williams Smith
4. Brown Johnson Smith

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You need SELF JOIN.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IF SQL Server (going by the posted image)

```
Declare @Table table (ID int,CLevel int,CParent int ,Name varchar(50))
Insert into @Table values 
(1,1,NULL,'Smith'),
(2,2,1    ,'Johnson'),
(3,2,1    ,'Williams'),
(7,3,2    ,'Brown')


;with cteHB (ID,CParent,Lvl,Name,PathName) as (
    Select  ID
           ,CParent
           ,Lvl=1
           ,Name
           ,PathName = cast(Name as varchar(500)) 
     From   @Table 
     Where  CParent is null
     Union  All
     Select cteCD.ID
           ,cteCD.CParent,cteHB.Lvl+1
           ,cteCD.Name 
           ,PathName = cast(concat(cteCD.Name,' ',cteHB.PathName) as varchar(500))
     From   @Table cteCD 
     Join   cteHB on cteCD.CParent = cteHB.ID)
Select A.ID
      ,A.CParent
      ,A.Lvl
      ,A.Name
      ,A.PathName
 From cteHB A
```

Returns

```
ID  CParent  Lvl  Name       PathName
1   NULL     1    Smith      Smith
2   1        2    Johnson    Johnson Smith
3   1        2    Williams   Williams Smith
7   2        3    Brown      Brown Johnson Smith
```